# Find total number of Unit Test in different DLLs

Tags: vb.net

I have a Project where we have different kinds of unit tests in different DLLs. I want to know total number of unit tests in whole solution as well as the Test Category, Owner name, etc. using some VB/C# code.

Actually, I need to prepare report daily, where I need to show how many unit test are written by whom and under which category

I do not want to open Visual Studio to know this.

This is an example signature for one of the unit tests:

```
<TestMethod()> <Owner("OwnerName"), TestCategory("Category22")>
Public Sub TestName()
    ............
    ............
End Sub
```

Comment: This information is somehow stored in the code, right? Are there attributes? Is the test project just methods? Is the owner name in the compiled code somewhere? (ie- not a comment).  There are probably not going to be any answers forthcoming unless you could show us a minimal but complete example of a test method with all of it's associated metadata.

Comment: i updated the main question with an example. Thanks

Comment: Hope you didn't think I forgot about you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the test methods are documented using .Net Framework attributes, you can use reflection to obtain the information you need. In VB.net, you can do it as follows.

```
'Imports System.Reflection
'Imports TestLibrary <- wherever the attributes are defined

Dim assy As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename)

Dim owner As OwnerAttribute
Dim category As TestCategoryAttribute

For Each t As Type In assy.GetTypes()
    For Each mi As MethodInfo In t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        If Not mi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(TestMethodAttribute)).Count() = 0 Then
            owner = mi.GetCustomAttribute(Of OwnerAttribute)()
            category = mi.GetCustomAttribute(Of TestCategoryAttribute)()

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0} : Owner='{1}' Category='{2}'", 
                                           mi.Name, owner.OwnerName, category.CategoryName)

        End If
    Next
Next
```

You do have to add the test framework DLL as a reference to the project. `filename` is the full path to the compiled assembly (EXE, DLL, etc). I didn't include error checking for space reasons.

If your test method isn't public, or it's static you can get it by changing the binding flags to `BindingFlags.NonPublic` or `BindingFlags.Static` respectively. (More information is available in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).)

Note that this method also works in C#

```cs
Assembly assy = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);

OwnerAttribute owner = null;
TestCategoryAttribute category = null;

foreach(Type t in assy.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (MethodInfo mi in t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute)).Count() != 0)
        {
            owner = mi.GetCustomAttribute<OwnerAttribute>();
            category = mi.GetCustomAttribute<TestCategoryAttribute>();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0} : Owner='{1}' Category='{2}'", 
                                           mi.Name, owner.OwnerName, category.CategoryName);
        }
   }
}
```